# How to configure nginx rewrite rules for fuelphp framework?

Tags: php, nginx, web, frameworks, fuelphp

Ive faced this problem when trying to execute an action from a controller in fuelphp framework, I get an 404 message from nginx. Im able to see, for e.g. localhost/index.php or just localhost, but when I try to access to an action-controller like localhost/index.php/login/huehue I get the 404 error. Can anyone help me? this app is currently working in apache, I was facing this trouble here too but everything got fine when I executed

> a2enmod rewrite

then I tried to search for equivalent config for nginx and I found this like:

> location /{ try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args 
>   /index.php?q=$request_uri }

or this:

> location /{
>    rewrite ^ /index.php?/$request_uri;}

but they didnt work for me. Ive spent several hours trying to find out the reason. This is my actual vhost file config for my site:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        root /var/www/nginx/goutmeet;
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name goutmeet.local www.goutmeet.local;

        location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args  /index.php?q=$request_uri @handler;
        }
 location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }
location @handler {
                rewrite ^ /index.php?/$request_uri;
        }
}
```

Id love to know how to solve this since using nginx sometimes is a better option than apache, and having this issue with fuelphp framework and not being able to use this two great tools together is awful. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The `try_files` directive can have one default action. You have three! See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for more.

Choose one:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$request_uri;
try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
```

I do not know which is the appropriate default action for your application. They all send the request to the PHP controller, but with different sets of parameters.

The first case passes the query string; the second case passes a single parameter containing the request URI; and the third case invokes the rewrite in the named location.

Comment: Sorry, tried all three individually and still the same result. And nope, didnt forget to restart/reload nginx. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for this problem, just add this line to config file:

```
error_page 404  /index.php;
```

I know is not the best solution but its been the only thing that has worked for me. In my opinion its acceptable since all routes should be managed by the framework and not by the web server.

Hope this helps someone.